# How do I slowly move my UISlider to the left or right with a touch of a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have these two buttons and if I press on the button on the left I want the slider to move slowly all the way to the left and the same thing when I press the button on the right to move the slider all the way to the right. The code I have right now moves the slider really quickly and I want it to be gradually.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(self.view!.bounds.width/2 - 150/2, self.view!.bounds.height/2 * 1.7, 150, 50))
        middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "mixerb1"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        middleSlider.maximumValue = 2.0
        middleSlider.minimumValue =  0.0
        middleSlider.value = 1.0
        middleSlider.continuous = true
        middleSlider.userInteractionEnabled = true
        middleSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(middleSliderChangeAudio), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
        self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        if node.name == "left" {
        print("slider moves to left")

        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
            self.middleSlider.value = self.middleSlider.minimumValue
            self.middleSlider.continuous = true
      }
   )
}


    if node.name == "right" {
    print("slider moves to right")

        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, animations: {
            self.middleSlider.value = self.middleSlider.maximumValue
            self.middleSlider.continuous = true
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `self.middleSlider.value` is not an animatable property, so you are not getting any animation at all.

Comment: What should I use than?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the setValue(_:animated:) method here [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISlider/setValue:animated:). 
Let us know how it goes .

Once you added this, wrap it in your animate with duration like this. Note that 10 seconds is just a hardcoded value, change the duration to whatever you want, same goes to the value that you wanted to set.

```
@IBAction func moveSlider(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(10, animations: {
        self.slider.setValue(1.0, animated: true)
    })


}
```

While you're at it, scroll up a bit to check out the documentation for the property value. So you have a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: The problem is you can't set the speed and anyhow it's broken.

Comment: Then just wrap it in a animate with duration() I tested that on Xcode 7.3 and it works perfectly

Comment: I didn't specifically mention animateWithDuration before the edit cause OP already has it, so I'm just pointing him to the direction that instead of setting the property value call the setValue method, also asking him to check the documentation for value so he knows whats actually going on

Comment: Yes I understand it now and it also works. I have one question and that is when I set the property continuous to true why doesnt it update the slider? The slider only works when I move it with my finger but not when I use the button.

Comment: I would have to see the code for the button for that. How was your IBAction?